# Get current index number QStackedWidget

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4

I have written a PyQt application in which I have used **QStackedWidget**. I want to get the current widget index/number. How can I retreive that?

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @S.Nick, well actually my code is very big and to provide a minimal reproducible example will take some time which I don't have at the moment. If you can just give me a one line hint or something that will be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> currentIndex : int
> This property holds the index position of the widget that is visible
> The current index is -1 if there is no current widget.
> By default, this property contains a value of -1 because the stack is initially empty.

see https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html#currentIndex-prop

---

> QWidget *QStackedWidget::currentWidget() const
> Returns the current widget, or nullptr if there are no child widgets.

see https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html#currentWidget